# mysql UPDATE and refreshing page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've got an issue where the page refreshes faster than the query is executed.

I use an UPDATE query to update my database with some values in my fields. And I got this under a button. But When I push this button (Which will refresh my website) it still shows the old values in my fields.

When I refresh the page again, it shows the values that I filled in. I added a image for a better explanation.[image]

I execute the query for getting the information for the table right away in my php code:

```
$dates = getStartAndEndTime($currentWeek, $currentYear);

$Query = "SELECT * FROM Productielijn1 WHERE Datum BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY Datum";
if($stmt = $dbCon->prepare($Query))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $dates[0], $dates[1]);

    if( $stmt->execute() === TRUE)
    {
        $Result = $stmt->get_result();

        while($row = $Result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $ArrayGegevens[] = $row;
        }
    }   
}
```

And when I press the button I do this:

```
//First edit button
if(isset($_POST['btnEdit1']))
{
    $date = strip_tags($_POST['Datum1']);

    $tempo = strip_tags($_POST['Tempo1']);
    $proddescrip = strip_tags($_POST['Productomshrijving1']);
    $amount = strip_tags($_POST['Aantal1']);

    $displayDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));

    $Query = "UPDATE productielijn1 SET Tempo= ?, Productomschrijving= ?, Aantal= ? WHERE Datum = ?";

    if($stmt = $dbCon->prepare($Query))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('isis', $tempo, $proddescrip, $amount, $date);

        if( $stmt->execute() === TRUE)
        {
            $Message2 = "De waardes van " . $displayDate ." zijn aangepast.";
            $MessageColor2 = "green"; 
        }
        else
        {
            $Message2 = "Het aanpassen is niet gelukt!";
            $MessageColor2 = "red"; 
        }
    }   
}
```

And I create my table like this:

```
    <table class ="PlanningTable">
        <tr>
            <th colspan='5'>Planning aanpassen voor huidige week (<?php echo $currentWeek ?>)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Tempo</th>
            <th>Product omschrijving</th>
            <th>Aantal/Volume</th>
            <th>Aanpassen</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        if (count($ArrayGegevens) != 0)
        {
            for ($k = 1; $k < count($ArrayGegevens)+1; $k++)
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><input type='date' name='Datum".$k."' value='".$ArrayGegevens[$k-1]['Datum']."'readonly></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='number' name='Tempo".$k."' value= '" .$ArrayGegevens[$k-1]['Tempo'] . "'></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' name='Productomshrijving".$k."' value ='". $ArrayGegevens[$k-1]['Productomschrijving'] ."'></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='number' name='Aantal".$k."' value='" . $ArrayGegevens[$k-1]['Aantal'] . "'></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='submit' name='btnEdit".$k."' value='Aanpassen'></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            echo"<tr>";
            echo "<td colspan='5' style='color: red;'>Voor deze week is er nog geen planning!</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=5><p class="Message" style='color: <?php echo $MessageColor2 ?>;'><?php echo $Message2 ?></p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

So is there a way that it will update my html values right away?

Comment: *"where the page refreshes faster than the query is executed"* - I don't see any redirection anywhere. What do you mean by that *exactly?*

Comment: Caching maybe?? Are you using AJAX? If you are, one of the keys there is the *asynchronous* part.

Comment: Well I *think* that's the issue, since the SELECT Query, gets the information from my database, but it gets my old information. (even when I executed the Update query first).

Comment: hard to say if all your code is in the same file or different file(s). use a header instead of meta refresh or js, since I have no idea what your refresh button does. Might just be a cache issue, as @JayBlanchard mentioned.

Comment: I think this is most likely to be because you are refreshing the visible data BEFORE you execute the UPDATE. **Please put the code in the order it appears in your script**

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is in the order it appears in my script. It first does the SELECT query and the button press is right after that query. The last part is in my HTML code and also as last.

Comment: Then **think about it** the first thing you do is SELECT from the DB and store results in an array. **Then after that you UPDATE the database** _Dear Rocket scientist, Should I do my space walk before or after the launch from the cape canavral???_

Comment: @RiggsFolly ye ur right.. god how stupid :x Time for a break. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    if(isset($_POST['btnEdit1']))
    {
        $date = strip_tags($_POST['Datum1']);

        $tempo = strip_tags($_POST['Tempo1']);
        $proddescrip = strip_tags($_POST['Productomshrijving1']);
        $amount = strip_tags($_POST['Aantal1']);

        $displayDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));

        $Query = "UPDATE productielijn1 SET Tempo= ?, Productomschrijving= ?, Aantal= ? WHERE Datum = ?";

        if($stmt = $dbCon->prepare($Query))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('isis', $tempo, $proddescrip, $amount, $date);

            if( $stmt->execute() === TRUE)
            {
                $Message2 = "De waardes van " . $displayDate ." zijn aangepast.";
                $MessageColor2 = "green"; 
            }
            else
            {
                $Message2 = "Het aanpassen is niet gelukt!";
                $MessageColor2 = "red"; 
            }
        }

              echo "<script>
                setTimeout(function(){
                    location.reload();
                }, 300);
                </script>";


}
```

---

Adding js code.

Comment: Isn't working since it will refresh my page every 300ms, and I cant fill in my information after the first edit

Comment: After updating the database, your page refreshs, but you can't see changes you made, then you must do the immediately second refresh to show updated info in your inputs. I use this solution in my app.